# how to use JSON data to morris bar chart ??[Laravel 5.2]

Tags: json, laravel, morris.js

i have a problem in passing json data from controller to morris bar chart,

this is my controller

```
$hits = Tourism::get([
        \DB::raw('nama as nama'),
        \DB::raw('jumlahview as jumlahview')
    ])->toJson();
```

and this is the blade

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="pageHits"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var data =JSON.parse('{{$hits}}}');

    Morris.Bar({
        element: 'pageHits',
        data: data,
        xkey: 'nama',
        ykeys: 'jumlahview',
        labels: ['Tourism'],
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true
    });
</script>
```

this is the value of $hits

```
[{"nama":"test1","jumlahview":10},{"nama":"palace","jumlahview":5}]
```

passing to the view

```
<div class="panel-body">
      <div id="morris-pagehits"></div>
 </div>
```

thanks

Comment: is the `$hits` returning things correctly? Are you passing the varible to the view?

Comment: @MatheusSilva yes, the value is there, and in json format [{"nama":"test1","jumlahview":10},{"nama":"palace","jumlahview":5}] .

Comment: just to make sure, how are you passing the variable to the view?

Comment: @MatheusSilva already put it at the top

Comment: I mean, are you using `return view()->with('hints', $myvariable);`?

Comment: yes i did that @MatheusSilva